# Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62

Tags: c, ubuntu, capture, libjpeg, image-capture

I'm trying to test a C program to access to webcam and make a snapshot, I found this code https://gist.github.com/bellbind/6813905

I built it using

```
 gcc -std=c99 capture.c -ljpeg -o capture
```

but the following error occurs

```
Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62
```

I'm using ubuntu 14.10
Any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What happens with the code you wrote yourself?

Comment: It's not written by me. I attached the link to the code on github

Comment: This site is not for explaining code written by other people on another site.

Comment: Thanks for the informations about the site, but did you read my question ? I'm not asking to explain the code, I am looking for fixing an error which can occur using any other code with jpeg library written by anyone.

Comment: If you have GraphicsMagick, please un-install it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This solved by installing `libjpeg62-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I was able to solve by setting the desired JPEG version in a config file located in `/usr/include/jconfig.h` in my Ubuntu 18.04 install. I simply set the value of `JPEG_VERSION`.
it was 62, and I set it to 80. I then had no trouble building my project and linking the correct version. Note that this file is auto generated by another `CMake` configuration file, so it is kind of a hack, and not the permanent solution.